# Obj-C determing integer values with isKindOfClass

Tags: objective-c

I need to check the type of each element in an array...

```
for(id obj in items) {
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
       //handle string case
    } else if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSInteger class]]) {  //THIS LINE GIVES ERROR
       //handle int case
    }
}
```

Of course `NSInteger` is just an alias for `int`, so how can I check for this at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't actually store `NSInteger` in an `NSArray`, since it isn't an object. If you are storing numbers in your array, they are most likely instances of `NSNumber`, so you would check for:

```
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) { ... }
```

iPhone Developer Tips [gives a good summary](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/nsnumber-and-nsinteger.html) of the difference between `NSInteger` and `NSNumber`.

Comment: ah, yeah that was a typo.

How would you differentiate floats from ints in the array if using NSNumber?

Comment: That gets a little more tricky. You can request the `objCType` of the `NSNumber`, and then test for 'i' or 'f'. See http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/objCType

Comment: Although technically correct, this answer is leading you astray. There's rarely a reason to add this non-OO smell to your Cocoa code. With the ability to add categories to existing classes, you can easily add a uniquePrefix_doMySpecialProcessing method to both NSString and NSNumber so that your loop can be properly polymorphic.

Comment: in this particular case that seems more complex, when in fact I only need to check 3 or 4 types.

It would help clean up the "is this NSNumber an int or a float" question though.